# Create external table Hive from CSV - Timestamp Issue

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, etl

I'm doing some research around Hive using the HDP Sandbox.

I have a CSV file with dates formatted as 9-11-2015 and I wanted to create a timestamp column to store the data. The command looks like this:

```
create external table product (
productid   string,
...
startdate   timestamp)                                
row format delimited fields terminated by ';'
location '/poc/product' TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

I got nulls for the startdate as the expected format is YYYY-MM-DD. This is a ETL problem and I was wondering what would be the right way to address this conversion without touching the data source.

I was wondering the options I have. 
I could do the following:

1. Create External Table using a string column for this field.
2. Do the conversion on Hive or Pig and generate another file / table.

I don't quite like this approach though. Any ideas / alternatives? How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My best alternative so far. Create the original table using a string field. Then creating a view like

create view product_ as 
select productid,
concat(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(startdate ,'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '  00:00:00.000') as startdate
from product

Is this the right approach?